# Apache Shiro + Guice - can't get the annotations to work

Tags: apache, guice, vaadin, shiro

So I was able to get Apache Shiro working with Guice (thanks to ShiroWebModule) on Vaadin. 
The Shiro annotations (`@RequiresAuthentication`, `@RequiresPermission`) work only on the main Vaadin Application class and inside custom classes. They don't work inside CustomComponent/Window classes.

I tried injecting the Window classes to the Application class with providers, through `injector.getInstance` and it still doesn't work...

I am new to Guice and Shiro, so maybe I am missing something?

Why does it work for other custom classes? This works as expected (throws exception)

```
public class TestClassImpl implements TestClass {

    @Override

    public void doSomeWork() {
        //this will throw an exception as expected
        test();
    }

    @RequiresAuthentication

    public void test() {

    }
}
```

This doesn't work as expected (the method is executed, the Apache Shiro annotation is ignored):

```
  public class LoginView extends CustomComponent {

    public LoginWindow() {
        setCompositionRoot(mainLayout);
        //this will execture but it should not
        test();
    }

    @RequiresAuthentication

    public void test() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Annotations like this at runtime usually involves AOP.

With Spring AOP, you cannot intercept calls to self : this is because Spring AOP generates proxy classes, and the interception happens on those proxies -> it can't intercept calls to self.

I suspect Guice AOP works in the same way.

NB: One of the differences between TestClass/Impl and LoginView is that TestClass implements an Interface; it might be the case that Guice treats Interface proxies and "normal class" proxies differently - I'd try changing the TestClass to extend an abstract class, and see what happens there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But the TestClassImpl works even if injected directly, without an interface. So this will not throw an exception (but it should) `injector.getInstance(LoginView.class);` and this works as expected (throws security exception)  `injector.getInstance(TestClassImpl.class);`. They both call an method inside the constructor which is annotated with @RequiresAuthentification.

Comment: Ok, there is a more fundamental problem here. Guice won't inject any classes inside CustomComponents. I don't know why. That definitely should work but I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Update. I have a workaround for this problem. Only constructor injection works in Components/Windows (don't know why). So I inject the service classes I need and these have Shiro annotations inside, which work. I will only need to programatically check Shiro roles/permission inside the Vaadin component/window classes.